# solr dataimport handler jndi websphere

Tags: solr, websphere, jndi, dataimporthandler

I am trying to use jndiName attribute in db-data-config.xml. This works great in tomcat. However having issues in websphere.

Following exception is thrown

"Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:"."

It seems like websphere has issues accessing jndi resource from Static code. Has anyone experienced this ?

```
 DataImporter  E org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: <REMOVE SQL from here>
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:428)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:154)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen issues with "java:" lookups being performed within static initializers or constructors.  What is db-data-config.xml?  What problem are you seeing?  Please include sample code, an error message from the logs, or a full exception stack trace if relevant.

Comment: I have added stacktrace here. db-data-config.xml is a configuration file for importing from database to Apache Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is using unmanaged threads here and is doing a JNDI lookup in the java: namespace in one of these threads. That is not supported in WebSphere because WebSphere identifies the java: namespace based on the thread performing the lookup. Tomcat does this based on the thread context class loader, which explains the difference in behavior. Note that unmanaged threads are not allowed by the J2EE specs, so that WebSphere's behavior is actually standards compliant.

Comment: Thanks, Now using jndiName="jdbc/testdb" instead of jndiName="java:comp/env/jdbc/testdb".